# Apache .htaccess force https and redirect to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to force https in my production apache server while in the same time redirect only the root route '/' to a subfolder '/front', so redirection to subfolder works fine but not https forcing.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /front [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R]
```

Comment: what should happen with `http://www.example.com/somefolder/` ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex /front/index.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R]
```